# DataGrid detect ONLY changes made by user

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a financial application where the user can enter invoice amounts into a DataGrid. The DataGrid is bound to an ObservableCollection of amounts, each amount is composed of Gross, VAT rate, VAT and Net. The requirement is that whenever the user enters two of the four values, the other two will be calculated by the software and displayed. Therefore for each column there is a event handler on CellEditEnding event (SelecChanged on the VAT rate which is a ComboBox) that is supposed to fire when their values are changed by the user.

My problem is, that the events fire not only upon user interaction but always when a value has changed, e.g. as a result of the calculation. Is there a way to detect only changes made by the user, i.e. make the events fire only when the user changed a value?

Here is the code:

XAML

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="dgvBetraege"
    Grid.Row="3"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Focusable="True"
    TabIndex="3"
    Margin="0,0,0,3"
    ItemsSource="{Binding currEinnahme.Betraege, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    AlternationCount="2"
    RowHeight="24"
    AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    SelectedItem="{Binding currBetrag, Mode=TwoWay}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    CellEditEnding="Betrag_CellEditEnding">

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Binding="{Binding Path=BetragID}"
            Visibility="Hidden">
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn 
            x:Name="colBetBtto"
            Header="Brutto"
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderRightAligned}"
            Width="*"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAligned}"
            Binding="{Binding Path=BttoBetrag, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn 
            x:Name="colBetUSt"
            Header="USt %"
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderRightAligned}"
            Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="mod:UStSatz">
                    <ComboBox 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.UStSaetze, Mode=OneWay}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="UStProz"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right"
                        ItemStringFormat="{}{0,19:N1} %"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding USt, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn 
            x:Name="colBetUStB"
            Header="USt"
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderRightAligned}"
            Width="*"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAligned}"
            Binding="{Binding Path=UStBetrag, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn 
            x:Name="colBetNtto"
            Header="Netto"
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderRightAligned}"
            Width="*"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAligned}"
            Binding="{Binding Path=NttoBetrag, StringFormat=N2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox s = (ComboBox)e.Source;
    vmEinnahme.CalculateBetrag((int)enumBetColIndex.UstSatz);
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void Betrag_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    vmEinnahme.CalculateBetrag(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you doing your calculation of the other values in code behind?

Comment: No, the code behind calls a calculation function in the ViewModel. Sorry, my object names are half german half english so it is not clear from reading the code. vmEinnahme is the view model and CalculateBetrag is the code that calculates the values. It gets the column index so it can decide which value has been changed by the user (or in unfortunately by the code as well).

Comment: make global bool `Calculating = false` and when you enter calculating function, at first line you set `calculating = true`, at the end `calculating = false` and inside `CellEdit` event you just set `if(calculating) { return; }` at first line

Comment: No problem; i know the problems with german/english variable names ;) Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can detach the `CellEditEnding` when doing your calculations and attach it when you finshed them. If you do it this way the `CellEditEnding` event won't get fired when you change the values in your calculation.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dgvBetraege.CellEditEnding -= Betrag_CellEditEnding;

    ComboBox s = (ComboBox)e.Source;
    vmEinnahme.CalculateBetrag((int)enumBetColIndex.UstSatz);

    dgvBetraege.CellEditEnding += Betrag_CellEditEnding;
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void Betrag_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    dgvBetraege.CellEditEnding -= Betrag_CellEditEnding;

    vmEinnahme.CalculateBetrag(e.Column.DisplayIndex);

    dgvBetraege.CellEditEnding += Betrag_CellEditEnding;
}
```

**edit**

Another solution would be using a `bool` to distinguish between user and program action. Could be look like this.

```
private bool _isCalculating = false;

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _isCalculating = true;

    ComboBox s = (ComboBox)e.Source;
    vmEinnahme.CalculateBetrag((int)enumBetColIndex.UstSatz);

    _isCalculating = false;

    e.Handled = true;
}

private void Betrag_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if(!_isCalculating)
    {
        vmEinnahme.CalculateBetrag(e.Column.DisplayIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your hints and answers. I have tried both solutions but they only seem to be workarounds, sometimes with strange effects (e.g. when I detach the eventhandler the debugger would crash in vs 2015). Moreover there seem to be many more occassions where the event handlers are being called, e.g. when the row gets/loses focus. Earlier I have tried to use interactivity library but I had a lot of problems with the combobox column with that mechanism. So I still have the question: how can I reliably distinguish between user and program interaction?

Comment: @pb_SKAT I added another solution to my answer.

Comment: Finally, since I am using MVVM, I ended up doing all calculation based on the PropertyChanged event in the model. There are still minor pains as the event is called after every digit the user enters as part of a number but at least the whole stuff works now and the ideological claims of MVVM as a clean separation between GUI and code is satisfied as well... Anyway, thanks again guys for your efforts!